# PHP: Dont' render row if value is empty

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

I have a a slider (Bootstrap 4) that renders some images that are uploaded on the server via FTP.

I am using the below code to render these images in front-end.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/files/images/<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
```

This works but the problem is that in front-end also the empty fields are rendered, showing empty elements.

This is how "empty" slides are now rendered in HTML.

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.local/wp-content/themes/new/files/images/" class="img-fluid is-slider-item">
```

A **working** image is rendered like this in HTML

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.local/wp-content/themes/new/files/images/2345672.png" class="img-fluid is-slider-item">
```

How can I prevent empty slides to be rendered in front-end?

Here the whole code

```
<?php if( have_rows('files') ): ?>
    <div class="carousel_bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <?php
                    $active = 'active';
                    $num = 0;
                    while ( have_rows('files') ) : the_row();
                        ?>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $num ?>" class="<?php echo $active ?>"></li>
                        <?php
                        $active = '';
                        $num += 1;
                    endwhile; ?>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <?php
                    $active = 'active';
                    while ( have_rows('files') ) : the_row();
                        ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active ?> screen08">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/files/images/<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /item -->
                        <?php $active = '';
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I tried is to move `<?php if( have_rows('files') ): ?>` inside `<div class="carousel_bg">` but it did not work

Any hint?

Many thanks!

Comment: Side note - I’m having trouble understanding `while ( have_rows('files']) ) : the_row();` for two reasons: the alternate syntax (which I like) looks like a malformed ternary when you add `the_row();` on the same line. Second, both of your functions look magical because there’s no indication of how you’re actually getting your data in and out of the loop. It smells like global variables.That aside, if `have_rows()` is working correctly, I see no reason why it would give you extra slides because when you’re out of data it will quit. So I would look at the whole `have_rows()` / `the_row()` thing

Comment: @TimMorton - It's Wordpress and [Advanced Custom fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row/). They are using `have_rows()` and `the_row()` in the way the manual says with the "standard" Wordpress code style. Wordpress has global states all over the place.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sure enough… I don’t work with wordpress, so I learned something new. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The picture we need is in sub_field ('image'), we need to check if there is a picture or not at the top of the loop. If not, skip this step.

Try this code

```
<?php if( have_rows('files') ): ?>
    <div class="carousel_bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <?php
                    $active = 'active';
                    $num = 0;
                    while ( have_rows('files') ) : the_row();
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                    if($image == "" ) continue;
                        ?>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $num ?>" class="<?php echo $active ?>"></li>
                        <?php
                        $active = '';
                        $num += 1;
                    endwhile; ?>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <?php
                    $active = 'active';
                    while ( have_rows('files') ) : the_row();
                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                    if($image == "" ) continue;
                        ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $active ?> screen08">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/files/images/<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" class="img-fluid is-slider-item" />
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /item -->
                        <?php $active = '';
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
<?php endif; ?>
```